# Given a triangle find the length of BC

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[image]

Given an ABC triangle , if $AB+AD=4$, find the length of BC.

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please improve the question by providing additional context, which ideally includes your thoughts on the problem and any attempts you have made to solve it. This information helps others identify where you have difficulties and helps them write answers appropriate to your experience level.

Comment: Well, believe me if you want to, but this question is not missing any details. I'll post what I have tried.

Comment: This is a standard text; in your specific case it misses the details of your mathematical context, i.e. what your "level" is, since this problem has many solutions if the toolkit is not restricted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: figure]
We are given that $∠BCD=θ$ and $∠BAD=2θ$. Also, $BD$ is the angular bisector of $∠ABC$.
We draw the circle $\Gamma$ with center $A$ and radius $|AD|$. $G$ is the intersection of $\Gamma$ and $AB$ such that $A$ is between $G$ and $B$. We know that $\angle AGD=\angle ADG$, because $|AD|=|AG|$, thus $\angle GAD=180^\circ-2\angle AGD$.
\begin{align}
\angle BCD&=\frac 12\angle BAD\\
&=\frac 12(180^\circ-\angle GAD)\\
&=\frac12(180^\circ-(180^\circ-2\angle AGD))\\
&=\angle AGD
\end{align}
Thus, $\angle BCD=\angle AGD$, thus
$$|BC|=|BG|=|BA|+|AG|=|BA|+|AD|=4$$

Comment: $\angle BCD=\frac 12\angle BAD$ Where does this come from?

Comment: The problem states that $\angle BCD=\theta$ and $\angle BAD=2\theta$. Also, $BD$ is the angular bisector of $\angle ABC$.

Comment: Oh, right... I thought $\angle BAD=20$. Time to sleep I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Continue ray $BA$. put it point $M$ such as $BM=4.$ For  triangle $MAD$ we have $AM=AD$ and $\angle AMD=\angle ADM=\theta.$ We can find the length of $BD$ from triangle $BMD.$ 
$$BD=\frac{4\sin \theta}{\sin (\theta+\alpha)}$$
From triangle $BCD$ we can find the length of $BC.$ 
$$BC=\frac{BD \sin(\theta+\alpha)}{\sin \theta}=4$$